# Tomcat 7.0.79 Server Authentication Issue

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, authentication

I am trying to login to the Tomcat Server and I cannot login but I have the correct credentials and I have tried all the solutions online.

Here is the useful code from the tomcat-users.xml file

```
    <tomcat-users>
      <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
      <user username=“collin” password=“bhbl21” roles="manager-gui"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

(I do no have it commented out, I know that is common.)

Here is my server.xml important stuff:

```
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
      type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
      description="User database that can be updated and saved"
      factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
      pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
   </GlobalNamingResources>
```

(I know some people put $CATALINA in front of the path name or something.)

I also made sure to restart the server. So I feel like it should work but it still does not let me login. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned

> I cannot login

I presume you have the default unmodified manager app in webapps.

I suggest try removing:

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
```

so you'll have something like this:

```
<tomcat-users>
      <user username=“collin” password=“bhbl21” roles="manager-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

also as tomcat-users.xml file's commented section mentions, need to define just the user and add specified role to it:

```
<!--
  NOTE:  By default, no user is included in the "manager-gui" role required
  to operate the "/manager/html" web application.  If you wish to use this app,
  you must define such a user - the username and password are arbitrary. It is
  strongly recommended that you do NOT use one of the users in the commented out
  section below since they are intended for use with the examples web
  application.
-->
```

for further reading reference:
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html

Comment: It still is not working even when I take out the rolename.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure there is no additional tag open or close in tomcat-users.xml file because by default  tag is present in this file and if you manually enter the user data . possibility is that two tag is mentioned in open or close state so recheck the complete file for the same.

and if still issue is exit then please share your logs for better understanding the issue .to check is there any error while logging or any other issue.